# Fast reports (C#) - generate few reports as one

Tags: fastreport

Is it possible to generate few reports and then show them all in same preview?
Example - I have one report, and I want to generate this report X times with different dataset every time. I can generate report once, preview it and when user close it I will generate second etc. But I want them all in one preview...

UPDATE (this works for me):

```
List<customClass> lista = customClass.ReadAll(parameter);
ReportPrilog5 rpt = new ReportPrilog5();

        FormPleaseWait frm = new FormPleaseWait();
        frm.show();
        Application.DoEvents();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            DataSetReports.Prilog5DataTable datasetName = new DataSetReports.Prilog5DataTable();
            WriteDataToDataset(dtPrilog5);

            rpt.RegisterData((System.Data.DataTable)dtPrilog5, "ABCDEFGH");
            rpt.SetParameterValue("pParameter", "Boris is cool");

            rpt.Prepare(true);
        }

        frm.Close();
        rpt.ShowPrepared();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Report.Prepare(bool:append)
```

to add reports together. And that is why it works for you.